Kubernetes connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused
I'm relatively new to Kubernetes, but I've been trying to install kubernetes inside a DigitalOcean's droplet. It works fine initially but after a while, I get this error when I try any kubectl command:
E0930 14:04:39.940782   77696 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0930 14:04:39.941445   77696 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0930 14:04:39.942841   77696 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0930 14:04:39.943720   77696 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
E0930 14:04:39.944631   77696 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
I don't have Docker installed yet, but I have kubectl, kubeadm, kubectl, and calico installed. I followed this installation guide: https://www.itsgeekhead.com/tuts/kubernetes-129-ubuntu-22-04-3/. Unfortunately I couldn't post it here.
I tried checking memory swap, which is off by default. SystemCGroup is set to true. I set CIDR pods to 10.10.0.0/16 when installing Calico, which is same as what I set during kubeadm init. Your kind assistance will be really appreciated. Thanks.

That error typically means the Kubernetes configuration file ($KUBECONFIG, by default ~/.kube/config) isn't correctly set up to point to the cluster.  Setting that up correctly is environment-specific, but the linked question has several common setups.  This is unrelated to your application's source code.

I hope this helps someone in the future. I was experiencing the same problem in DigitalOcean Droplets. I had run export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf when creating, and kubectl worked OK at first. But it could fail after a few minutes. Solution: Apparently the issue is admin.conf. If you run scp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf, then run kubectl --kubeconfig ./admin.conf get nodes, and you get the right results, run this: mkdir -p $HOME/.kube sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
